# Puppet - add text in desired place

Tags: puppet

i want to add, using puppet, text in existing file in desired place. Structure of the file is as follows:

```
[OPTION1]
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I want to add text between `aaa` and `bbb`. For now I have figured out how to add text at the end of the file with:

```
file { '/home/file.txt': ensure => present, } ->
    file_line { 'Add text to /home/file.txt':
    path => '/home/file.txt',  
    line => 'added_text'
```

Should I use `awk` or `sed` (i saw it somewhere on google) or there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_line` has an `after` parameter, which you should set to the line you want the text to be inserted after:

```
file_line { 'Add text to /home/file.txt':
  path  => '/home/file.txt',
  line  => 'added_text',
  after => 'aaa',
}
```

See the [file_line documentation](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#file_line) for a full list of supported features.